# Does getting Response from Request get all of the body? (golang, net/http)

Tags: http, go, web-crawler

I am trying to avoid wasting traffic by reading http response body only when I see correct **content-type** and **content-length** smaller than set threshold.

```
httpRequest, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
httpResponse, err := httpClient.Do(httpRequest)
contentType := httpResponse.Header.Get("Content-Type")

// ... check for correct contentType    

// Read body into memory?
content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(httpResponse.Body)
```

Is it correct assumption that if I make GET request, I will be getting all the body regardless whether I call last line **iotuil.ReadAll(httpResponse.Body)**  or not?

If so, the only way I could think of avoiding wasting traffic is to use HEAD request, but I would have to make another GET request if I actually want to read the body. Also do I get correct **content-length** value if I make HEAD request?

What would be the best strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application should Close the response body if the application does not want to read it. In recent versions of Go, the net/http [client will close the underlying network connection instead of slurping up the remainder of the response body from the network](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ce8341554caa8be64aeafd9bf2077a98db462fda).

The Content-Length header may not be set. In this case, the application should read up to the threshold number of bytes or EOF.

In all cases, close the response body when the application is done with the response.

There is no guarantee that the response to a HEAD request includes a Content-Length header.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Are you saying the net/http **won't send TCP packets** to read body until **ioutil.ReadAll(httpResponse.Body)** is called?

Comment: If the client does not read the response body, then the server sends data until the TCP window fills or the client closes the connection. Closing the response body is the only option for reducing the amount of data transferred over the network.